# Testing Applications using Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application that is multi-tenant and uses Azure AD for authentication. The application is provisioned in Azure AD as Web application and has a return URL `https://localhost:someport`. 
In local development mode I launch it, sign in and test etc.

Now, its time to make the release official so I have to obviously change the return URL to the official site like `https://myapplication.cloudapp.net` something.

Now, when testing locally, how can I use Azure AD for authentication since return URL needs to be changed otherwise. How is this taken care of ?

Is there any guidance on how test environment can be totally separated from production ?

Comment: You can have multiple Redirect URIs for a single app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be asking two different questions.

1) If you are asking how you can keep completely different entries: you can always create two application entries in Azure AD, one for development and the other for production. In that case you will have different clientIDs, different redirect URIs, and so on.

2) If you are asking how you can have two instances (one running locally, the other in the cloud) and one single codebase: You can update your Azure AD entry to have both return URIs, and use code similar to `RedirectToIdentityProvider` in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs to change the return URI you want to use at runtime according to the environment your app is running on.
HTH
V.